# Android app to get altitude of places to use in field visit?

Tags: gps, elevation, altitude

I want to verify the height of the ground which is provided to me with the help of an app if available. Of course, I am aware an  app will not give me exact value but for me, it works if it shows relative height also.

Comment: Did you try an internet search.  Eg, Google search for "Android app to get altitude" shows several results:  https://www.google.com/search?q=Anroid+app+to+get+altitude&rlz=1C1EJFA_enAU783AU783&oq=Anroid+app+to+get+altitude&aqs=chrome..69i57.5072j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @SonofaBeach but remember that users results may differ ~ https://spreadprivacy.com/google-filter-bubble-study/

Comment: I’d be surprised if an answer to such a broad question couldn’t be found by a simple internet search, Google or otherwise.  That Google URL was ONLY one example.

Answer (score 1):

[OruxMap](https://www.oruxmaps.com/cs/en/) is one of the best android apps for navigation. You can get an approximate altimeter using device barometer Compass, you can use it for navigation, save your tracks, waypoints and POIs, and many more. It is free.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Topographer gives you coordinates and error estimate. Also implements accuracy enhancement techniques.